# Elasticsearch - search for numbers / price with decimal places

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, search

How can I search for documents in Elasticsearch that have numeric field with value having  decimal places?
My Mapping is as follows:

```
POST /itemnew/_doc
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
        },
        "purchase_price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "sale_price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "sku": {
          "type": "string",
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "ngram_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",        
}
```

Sample document is as follows:

```
PUT itemnew/_doc/3
{
  "company_id":"4510339694428161" ,
        "item_type": "goods",
        "name":"Apple sam" ,
        "purchase_price":"45.50" ,
        "sale_price":"50",
        "sku": "sku 123"
}
```

I get NumberFormatException when I try the following query: GET itemnew/_search

````
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "45.5",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "purchase_price",
              "sale_price",
              "sku"
            ],
            "type": "most_fields"
         ```
How can I search for documents in Elasticsearch that have numeric field with value having  decimal places?Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you }
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lenient top-level parameter for a multi-match query here. Adding `lenient` just ignore exception that occurs due to format failures.

> lenient (Optional, Boolean) If true, format-based errors, such as
> providing a text query value for a numeric field, are ignored.
> Defaults to false.

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
PUT testidx
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "purchase_price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "sale_price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
PUT testidx/_doc/1
{
  "company_id": "4510339694428161",
  "item_type": "goods",
  "name": "Apple sam",
  "purchase_price": "45.50",
  "sale_price": "50",
  "sku": "sku 123"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST testidx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "hello",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "purchase_price",
              "sale_price",
              "sku"
            ],
            "lenient": true,
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  :) its working fine only for decimal, but I have a field in my indexed documents where i need to search with case sensitive search,price decimal search , partial matching(like when i search a string "app" ,must be show "apple","Apple","app"  )should work